# VBA - kill background IE process, leave foreground running

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Is there a way to code ending Internet Explorer background processes (yellow) while leaving the IE foreground process (green) running, using winmgmt service?

[image: screenhot]

This code closes every IE process it finds:

```
Sub KillIE()

    Dim cProc As Object
    Dim oProc As Object

    Set cProc = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

    For Each oProc In cProc
        If oProc.Name = "iexplore.exe" Then oProc.Terminate
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried looping through `oProc` properties, but there doesn't seem to be a "Type" property that would tell me which one is the background one. Neither can I work it out from any of the 45 available properties.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There isn't really a straight-forward way to do this AFAIK. You might just need to enumerate all of the window handles associated with the process id and check to see if they are visible with `GetWindowLong`.